# Replace odd number comma character with a space

Tags: java, string

How can I use replace function to replace the occurrence of comma at odd position with a space? So I would like to replace comma at 1,3,7,9...to be space...

String text = [[[13, 68], [134,681], [13,6], [17, 68], [13, 68], [13, 681], [135, 68], [136, 68], [13, 68]]]

Thank you for your time.

The Output string should look like as follows: I can use replace function twice to replace "[" and "]" but I don't understand how I can remove odd number occurrence of comma using "Java"

```
13 68, 134 681,13 6, 17 68, 13 68, 13 681, 135 68, 136 68, 13 68
```

**Update1** with Regex: The following data has X and Y coordinates for the geometry data type of sql server.

text = [[[148607.181567725, 6818657.60249623], [147539.268528918, 6817188.04749019], [144563.526399356, 6817136.65513745], [144921.154209564, 6818629.77966401], [146841.517476705, 6819929.72166114], [148012.482915056, 6819763.28604383], [148607.181567725, 6818657.60249623]]]

**Output**: [[[148607.181567725 6818657.60249623 147539.268528918 6817188.04749019 144563.526399356 6817136.65513745 144921.154209564 6818629.77966401 146841.517476705 6819929.72166114 148012.482915056 6819763.28604383 148607.181567725 6818657.60249623]]]

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: can you replace ], with something, then replace the rest of commas then replace back to ], or use regular expression to replace comma but not ], or split string to separate [whatever] chunks and rebuild with the different separator. It's quite unclear what are inputs

Comment: how should the result look like?

Comment: @Maverick  I have tried using replace function. My original requirement is to remove "[" and "]" as well which I have managed to do using String replace function. I will update my post further

Comment: @YCF_L: I have updated my post on how the output should look like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex and use `$1 $2` as replacement for captured digits

`\\[*(\\d+)\\W*,\\W*(\\d+)\\]*`

`\\[*`  : zero or more occurrences of `[`

`(\\d+)`: capture one or more digits which later used as replacement `$1`

`\\W*,`  : zero or more non-word characters and `,`

`(\\d+)` : second capture group for replacement as `$2`

`\\]*`   : zero or more occurrences of `]`

```
    String s = "[[[13, 68], [134**,** 681], [13**,** 6], [17, 68], [13, 68], [13, 681], [135, 68], [136, 68], [13, 68]]]";
    String pattern = "\\[*(\\d+)\\W*,\\W*(\\d+)\\]*";
    System.out.println(s.replaceAll(pattern, "$1 $2"));
```

Output :

```
13 68, 134 681, 13 6, 17 68, 13 68, 13 681, 135 68, 136 68, 13 68
```

**Update** : For unsigned decimal numbers you can use

[`\\[*(\\d*\\.?\\d+)\\D*,\\D*(\\d*\\.?\\d+)\\]*`](https://regex101.com/r/TurPBj/2)

Demo

```js
const regex = /\[*(\d*\.?\d+)\D*,\D*(\d*\.?\d+)\]*/g;

const str = `[[[13, 68], [134**,** 681], [13**,** 6], [17, 68], [13, 68], [13, 681], [135, 68], [136, 68], [13, 68]]]`;

const str2 = `[[[148607.181567725, 6818657.60249623], [147539.268528918, 6817188.04749019], [144563.526399356, 6817136.65513745], [144921.154209564, 6818629.77966401], [146841.517476705, 6819929.72166114], [148012.482915056, 6819763.28604383], [148607.181567725, 6818657.60249623]]]`;

const subst = `$1 $2`;
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);
const result2 = str2.replace(regex, subst);
console.log(result);
console.log(result2);
```

Note : for signed values

like  `[[[-148607.181567725, -6818657.60249623], [-147539.268528918, -6817188.04749019],`

use [`\\[*(-?\\d*\\.?\\d+)\\D*,[^-\\d]*(-?\\d*\\.?\\d+)\\]*`](https://regex101.com/r/GIF3J1/2)

Comment: Thanks: I am running this code on a groovy compiler which accepts java code but I am getting the following error "Illegal String Body character after dollar sign
Solution:either escape a literal dollar sign "\$5" or bracket the value expression"

Comment: i am looking into groovy syntax now for replacement literals like `$1 $2` , it's works perfect in java and the demo (JS) , i will update it when i am done

Comment: @user3384231 try using `s.replaceAll(pattern, "\$1 \$2"));`

Comment: Code got compiled. I am testing it out with few scenarios. Will update u soon.

Comment: I tried the string which I posted and it worked but I am adding the data for one more possible scenario but the regex is not working. I will update my post with the string I tried and output I got.

Comment: you are genius. Thank you very much. Issue got resolved.

Comment: thanks for the compliments , i am glad that i could help and happy coding

Answer (score 0):

> replace the occurrence of comma at odd position with a space

It sounds like what you really need is to replace the commas between brackets. If so, then how about using a regex to find these characters?

```
String s = "[[13, 68], [134**,** 681], [13**,** 6], [17, 68], [13, 68], [13, 681], [135, 68], [136, 68], [13, 68]]]";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("\\][ ,]+\\[", "] ["));
```

Output:

```
[[13, 68] [134**,** 681] [13**,** 6] [17, 68] [13, 68] [13, 681] [135, 68] [136, 68] [13, 68]]]
```

Edit:

I've removed the wrong commas, here's an updated version:

```
String s = "[[13, 68], [134**,** 681], [13**,** 6], [17, 68], [13, 68], [13, 681], [135, 68], [136, 68], [13, 68]]]";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("\\[([^,]+)[ ,]+([^,]+)\\]", "[$1 $2]"));
```

Output:

```
[[13 68], [134** ** 681], [13** ** 6], [17 68], [13 68], [13 681], [135 68], [136 68], [13 68]]]
```

Comment: For example,  I want to replace the comma between 13 and 68 with a space and see the output in my updated question

Comment: 13 68, 134 681,13 6, 17 68, 13 68, 13 681, 135 68, 136 68, 13 68

Comment: @user3384231 oops, I've replaced the wrong commas. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: No problem...I tried ur regex also but its giving me "Illegal String Body character after dollar sign
Solution:either escape a literal dollar sign "\$5" or bracket the value expression".  I am running this code on a groovy compiler which accepts java code